# What counts as an "emotion" that can be Soothed or Rioted?

Tags: magic, magical-theory, cosmere, mistborn

There are many examples in all of the Mistborn novels of Allomancers using brass and zinc to Soothe and Riot emotions. Most of the time, these emotions are clearly definable as emotions: hope, anger, despair, etc. However, occasionally Allomancers are shown to affect more esoteric things: Vin is shown Rioting curiosity and boredom when

> infiltrating the Fadrex cache.

Is there any clear definition of what counts as an "emotion" that can be affected by Allomancy? Is there an example of an Allomancer trying to Soothe an emotion and failing, because that emotion isn't a valid 'target'?

Comment: My gut tells me there's no actual limit like that, but because there aren't any counter-examples, it'd be hard to prove.  Beyond looking for a particular reaction, emotional allomancy doesn't grant any insight into the mind of the target.

Comment: My hope is that there's some record of Sanderson answering a question like this at a panel. Otherwise I agree that this isn't likely to be answered.

Comment: one way to check for that is to search [Arcanum](https://wob.coppermind.net/) but I don't ever remember hearing of that kind of limit. I suspect that it may be limited by the collective perception of these things (as spren are)

Comment: A very good question, but I fear a definitive answer likely isn't possible without asking Brandon Sanderson. My own guess is that it's very broad, since you can use Soothing/Rioting to completely control koloss and kandra -- maybe even humans with Hemalurgic spikes, although that would probably require more power than any actual Allomancer could manage (maybe with massive Feruchemical Nicrosil boost...). But I don't really have evidence for that, as Hemalurgy is weird.